# Flume- twitter -java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: twitter, flume

I am trying to get twitter messages into hdfs. I got no error message, but still I am not able to find out the output in hdfs.

Here is my conf file:

```
    TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
    TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sinks = hdfs
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = ...
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = ...
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken =  ...
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret =  ...

    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = medicare, PacificSource, India, hadoop
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/flumegrab/twitter/year=%Y/month=%m/day=%d
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this question is extremely unclear. Please edit it to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tell us what you're trying to do, what you expect the code to do, and what happens instead. With that information, maybe we can help.

Comment: I am trying to setup twitter messages into hdfs. Here is my conf file:

Comment: Much better! If you still get the Exception, then please show us the Exception, and the code where it originates.

Comment: I was still getting this exception:Exception in thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
It got resolved after I commented this line in flume-env.sh
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx1000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"

The memory settings are there on conf file:
# describe the channel
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=100

Answer (score 2):

It got resolved after I commented this line in flume-env.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx1000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

The memory settings are there on conf file:

```
# describe the channel
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=100
```

Comment: Congratulations on solving it yourself, and thank you for letting the rest of us know how you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I know OP figured it out, but his solution didn't help me thet much and I see this question gets viewed from time to time so I'll share my solution too.

The issue is, well not enough heap space, which I see OP is manipulating in his env variable JAVA_OPTS as well. I simply increased MaxHeap like in the answer to this question and I was fine. [Increase Flume MaxHeap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56997665/increase-flume-maxheap)